# Null sets w.r.t. product measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,A,m)$ and $(Y,B,n)$ be two measure spaces, and for every $x\in X$, let $B_x\in B$ have zero measure: $n(B_x)=0$. Is it true that $\cup_{x\in X}(\{x\}\times B_x)$ has zero outer measure w.r.t to the product measure $m\otimes n$ (and is therefore measurable in the Caratheodory sense)? We may assume that the measure spaces are sigma-finite, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's a counterexample in Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* (example (c) in section 8.9).

The example depends on the Continuum Hypothesis, so one might object that we haven't  really shown a counterexample exists, since we don't know that CH is true. But note this:

> > > Suppose that CH implies  some proposition P is false. Then it's impossible to prove P in ZFC (unless of course ZFC is inconsistent).

Proof: It's known that (if ZFC is consistent then) ZFC does not prove not-CH.

> > **Corollary** A counterexample depending on CH is worth more than you might think, even if you don't believe CH.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful indeed, and fully answers my question. Why I wanted to know this is because I was reading Reed&Simon, Vol. I, Section II.4 (Tensor products of Hilbert spaces), and it seemed to me that in their argument in the middle of page 51, where they conclude that the function f is zero almost everywhere w.r.t. the product measure, they implicitly assumed that the statement in my question is true - which you just showed to be wrong. I would be very interested to know if you see the same flaw in their argument, or if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Well  I don't have that book, so I really don't know what you're talking about. Possibly relevant is that if the set you ask about is measurable then Fubini implies it does have measure zero.

Comment: OK, thanks. Thinking over their argument more carefully, Fubini indeed solves the problem, so I might delete my previous comment. The original problem is still very interesting, I think, and I find it intriguing that CH is needed for a counterexample.